# Capturing keydown event of MS Word using C#

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to develop an office add-on and need to capture the keydown event on MS-Word using C#. can somebody give me an example on how i can do that?

Comment: Some own initiative is also appreciated.

Comment: @styxxy, Yes but most of the tutorials i found focus on adding content and/or controls to a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of: [How to get the "KeyPress" event from a Word 2010 Addin (developed in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120199/how-to-get-the-keypress-event-from-a-word-2010-addin-developed-in-c)

In that question [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800908/700926) links to a similar question on the MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/7198a84f-4a37-474b-93b5-1e6f38d5d139. In the accepted answer on the MSDN forum it is stated that:

> there's nothing in the Word API or VSTO that can pick up keystrokes.
>   There's nothing built-in that you can use in a VSTO project to pick up
>   the keystrokes.

However, the accepted answer on the MSDN forum also talks about a possible solution involving the [`WindowSelectionChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.windowselectionchange%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event - it might be useful to look in to.

Comment: Thanks, WindowSelectionChange seems to be what i need