# Keyboard hook fires multiple times in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto, keyboard-hook

This is in reference to a question asked in [Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770647/detecting-text-changes-in-word-2016-from-vsto-add-in/33897595#33897595)

While the answer provided by Dirk Vollmar works, I noticed that hitting one key triggers KeyboardHookCallBack 10-12 times and I am not able to capture accurately the sequence the keys are being hit in.

Pardon me if my question is stupid but is there a way to make sure that the KeyboardHookCallBack is triggered only once for each key? I have been trying this for some time now without any luck.

I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to implement auto-complete feature with intellisense in MS Word. I had decided that every time user hits a space bar I should try to track what keys the user had pressed since he last hit the space bar. Based on the solution at [Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770647/detecting-text-changes-in-word-2016-from-vsto-add-in/33897595#33897595) I wasn't getting the keys pressed in a proper sequence and the hook callback executed multiple times. Although I had found a dirty way to get around the problem, the solution wasn't full-proof. After spending a few days I have come up with a workaround and I feel this one should work. Here it goes:

```
private IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    string key = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)wParam).ToString‌();
    if (key == "Space")
    {
        Word.Selection sel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
        Word.Range rng = sel.Range.Paragraphs[1].Range;
        object unitWord = Word.WdUnits.wdWord;
        object countN1 = -1;
        sel.MoveStart(ref unitWord, ref countN1);
        string userInput = sel.Words[1].Text;
        sel.MoveRight(ref unitWord, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps all the people struggling with similar issue.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with the hookcall back being executed multiple times. How did you solve this?