# Adding key event handlers for PowerPoint 2016 VBA Add-in or C# VSTO

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, powerpoint

I'm trying to set custom shortcuts to run certain macros (e.g., if a user presses Ctrl+Shift+L, run the load_all_cat_images sub). But I want it to be self-contained in the add-in so I don't want users to have to also then download a 3rd party Windows or Office hotkey manager software.

I know in Excel add-ins and VTSOs there are ways to put in key event handlers. Is there a way someone could show me to insert the same functionality for PowerPoint 2016?

Comment: The only possibility is the Windows API and you'll find examples in the VSTO forum on MSDN. However, I do know that a few years ago this stopped working in PowerPoint. Whether the functionality has been restored in version 2016 I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate but similar use case can be found for Word, but works for any Office application when implemented via VSTO or VBA, using keyboard and mouse hooks:

[Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770647/detecting-text-changes-in-word-2016-from-vsto-add-in)