# Manipulating text of a document while it's open

Tags: ms-office, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk, openoffice-writer

Is it possible to extract, modify or simply read text in an Office while user types in words?  It it possible through OpenXML SDK & InterOp library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Microsoft Office Interop API for Word in a couple of projects, and surely, you can access the content of the document, even while a user is editing it.

I suggest you take a look at some tutorials to get you started, and if you encounter some problems, you can always return and ask.

Beware though - if you are expecting to be able to read the content each time a new character or word has been entered in the document, you might get disappointed, as there currently are no events raised when this happens. See this related question/answer for further details on this: [Capturing keydown event of MS Word using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000645/capturing-keydown-event-of-ms-word-using-c-sharp)