# is there any event for compose mail when user type or change email body

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

how i can know if user change/start type email body any event instead of, write and beforesend events?

I try to check and validate special work when user typing to show help list to select from template

any reply will help me so much

Thanks you

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120199/how-to-get-the-keypress-event-from-a-word-2010-addin-developed-in-c/8800908#8800908

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such event. MailItem.PropertyChange will not fire as the user types the message body. Word Object Model (Inspector.WordEditor returns an instance of the Word's Document object) also provides no useful events for this.

The best you can do is install a Windows message hook or subclass the Word editor window procedure and process the keyboard events.